# Laravel package migrations not available after migrate:fresh

Tags: laravel

I've installed [this package](https://github.com/themsaid/wink) following the instructions.

Now if I run `migrate:fresh` the wink tables are not there. For other packages the tables are created so I'm not sure why this is.

If I run `php artisan wink:migrate` it does create the tables, but as I often run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` I would like the wink tables to be created on that command and directly seed them with data like I do with other packages.

Comment: Some packages allow you to "publish" them, which extracts configuration and migrations to `config/{package}.php`, and `database/migrations/{package}.php`. I don't see that listed for this package, but might be worthwhile to reach out via their GitHub page to see if that option is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the author of this package creates a custom command for migration and as can see on official documentation of it `After each update, make sure you run these commands: php artisan wink:migrate`.

You can overcome this by creating a custom `Artisan` command.

For example make `php artisan make:command FreshDatabase` and in that class add what you need, i.e. call:

```php
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
php artisan wink:migrate
```

How to create a custom command, you can see on the Laravel Documentation. Source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan